# Using groovy, how do you pipe multiple shell commands?

Tags: bash, shell, groovy, process

Using Groovy and it's `java.lang.Process` support, how do I pipe multiple shell commands together?

Consider this bash command (and assume your username is `foo`):

```
ps aux | grep ' foo' | awk '{print $1}'
```

This will print out usernames - one line for some processes related to your user account.

Using Groovy, the [ProcessGroovyMethods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.5/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.html#or(java.lang.Process,%20java.lang.Process)) documentation and code says I should be able to do this to achieve the same result:

```
def p = "ps aux".execute() | "grep ' foo'".execute() | "awk '{print $1}'".execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

However, I can't get any text output for anything other than this:

```
def p = "ps aux".execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

As soon as I start piping, the println does not print out any anything.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works for me :

```
def p = 'ps aux'.execute() | 'grep foo'.execute() | ['awk', '{ print $1 }'].execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

for an unknown reason, the parameters of awk can't be send with only one string (i don't know why! maybe bash is quoting something differently). If you dump with your command the error stream, you'll see error relative to the compilation of the awk script.

**Edit** : In fact,

1. `"-string-".execute()` delegate to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(-string-)`
2. It's bash job to handle arguments containing spaces with ' or ". Runtime.exec or the OS are not aware of the quotes
3. Executing `"grep ' foo'".execute()` execute the command grep, with `'` as the first parameters, and `foo'` as the second one : it's not valid. the same for awk

Comment: While @tim_yates's answer solved my particular problem in a different way (and I'm very grateful for that), this answer addresses the OP question of Groovy's `or` operator and `Process` objects, so I'll award it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can do this to just let the shell sort it out:

```
// slash string at the end so we don't need to escape ' or $
def p = ['/bin/bash', '-c', /ps aux | grep ' foo' | awk '{print $1}'/].execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

Comment: Yeah, I could, and that may be the way I need to go, but do you know why the 'or' method does not work as defined in the docs?

Comment: It's something to do with awk. Not sure what, but it doesn't like being run in this way

Comment: Interesting - the slashy approach worked.  Using double quotes did not.  Go figure!

Comment: this answer is not false.. but it didn't answer to the original question : how to use the | operator between Process object in groovy. you execute only one command through bash, and it's bash which pipe the processes, not groovy

Comment: @tim_yates yep, I think it is related to awk or the nested single quotes.  Using a slashy string solved the problem for me, so I guess I'll use that moving forward.  Unfortunately, the question on Groovy piping still remains :/

Answer (score 8):

This has worked for me

```
def command = '''
    ps aux | grep bash | awk '{print $1}'
'''
def proc = ['bash', '-c', command].execute()
proc.waitFor()
println proc.text
```

If you want to run multiple commands, you can add it in the command.

```
def command = '''
    ls -ltr
    cat secret
'''
def proc = ['bash', '-c', command].execute()
proc.waitFor()
println proc.text
```

Comment: This is the same as @tim_yates answer above - he's just using a slash-string instead of a heredoc :)

Comment: @LesHazlewood The difference for me was that this one worked and the slash-string one didn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it async I recommend

```
 proc.consumeProcessOutputStream(new LineOrientedOutputStream() {
        @Override
        protected void processLine(String line) throws IOException {
           println line
        }
    }
    );
```