# in groovy run process failure with command having spaces in file arg

Tags: java, bash, groovy, process

It shouldn't matter that this is groovy. When I execute a command that includes a file argument having embedded spaces, the command fails. However, I can **pwd**. I can also run the exact same command from the command line. This is running on Linux Mint - again, not that it should matter. Here is a snippet from my log showing both the pwd command and the second command (flac piped to lame).

```
2017-06-26T08:50:00.750 runCommand pwd, /home/worldwidewilly/Music/album-rip/Dixie Cups, The
2017-06-26T08:50:00.789 OUT: /home/worldwidewilly/Music/album-rip/Dixie Cups, The

2017-06-26T08:50:00.790 ERROR: 
2017-06-26T08:50:00.791 runCommand flac -cd "Iko Iko".flac | lame -b 320 - "Iko Iko".mp3, /home/worldwidewilly/Music/album-rip/Dixie Cups, The
2017-06-26T08:50:00.794 OUT: 
2017-06-26T08:50:00.795 ERROR: 
flac 1.3.0, Copyright (C) 2000-2009, 2011-2013  Josh Coalson & Xiph.Org Foundation
flac comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you are
welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  Type `flac' for details.


"Iko: ERROR initializing decoder
      init status = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_INIT_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE

An error occurred opening the input file; it is likely that it does not exist
or is not readable.

Iko".flac: ERROR initializing decoder
           init status = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_INIT_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE

An error occurred opening the input file; it is likely that it does not exist
or is not readable.

|: ERROR initializing decoder
   init status = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_INIT_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE

An error occurred opening the input file; it is likely that it does not exist
or is not readable.

lame: ERROR initializing decoder
      init status = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_INIT_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE

An error occurred opening the input file; it is likely that it does not exist
or is not readable.

"Iko: ERROR initializing decoder
      init status = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_INIT_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE

An error occurred opening the input file; it is likely that it does not exist
or is not readable.

Iko".mp3: ERROR initializing decoder
          init status = FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_INIT_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE

An error occurred opening the input file; it is likely that it does not exist
or is not readable.
```

It really does not seem to like the embedded spaces in the song name in either the flac or lame command. Nor does it seem to like the pipe.

The command in question runs just fine from the command line.

```
worldwidewilly@hal9000 ~/Music/album-rip/Dixie Cups, The $ flac -cd "Iko Iko".flac | lame -b 320 - "Iko Iko".mp3

flac 1.3.0, Copyright (C) 2000-2009, 2011-2013  Josh Coalson & Xiph.Org Foundation
flac comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you are
welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  Type `flac' for details.

Iko Iko.flac: done         
LAME 3.99.5 64bits (http://lame.sf.net)
Using polyphase lowpass filter, transition band: 20094 Hz - 20627 Hz
Encoding <stdin> to Iko Iko.mp3
Encoding as 44.1 kHz j-stereo MPEG-1 Layer III (4.4x) 320 kbps qval=3
```

---

EDIT

---

Using *sh -c* rang bells. I used it in a Gradle script six or seven years ago. However, what I have does still does not work. I believe I am doing as suggested. Now, you will notice from the logs below I am getting **-cd: 1: -cd: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string**. Doing a bit of research, it  seems the shell is doing word splitting. Not sure what I should do about this. The solutions I saw did not apply to JVM and seemed inappropriate.

Here is my code (which I failed to include originally):

```
def mp3FromFlac(flac) {
    log "mp3FromFlac ${flac.name}"
    def name = flac.name - '.flac'
    def path_to_song = flac.parentFile.absolutePath
    def flacCmd = /flac -cd "${name}".flac/
    def lameCmd = /lame -b 320 -q 0 - "${name}".mp3/

    log "mp3FromFlac: flacCmd: ${flacCmd}"
    log "mp3FromFlac: lameCmd: ${lameCmd}"
    def cmd = /sh -c '${flacCmd} | ${lameCmd}'/
    log "mp3FromFlac: cmd: ${cmd}"
    def proc = cmd.execute(null, new File(path_to_song))
    log "mp3FromFlac: OUT: ${proc.in.text}"
    log "mp3FromFlac: ERROR: ${proc.err.text}"
}
```

And, here is my current log file:

```
2017-06-27T15:12:42.436 mp3FromFlac Iko Iko.flac
2017-06-27T15:12:42.437 mp3FromFlac: flacCmd: flac -cd "Iko Iko".flac
2017-06-27T15:12:42.437 mp3FromFlac: lameCmd: lame -b 320 -q 0 - "Iko Iko".mp3
2017-06-27T15:12:42.437 mp3FromFlac: cmd: sh -c 'flac -cd "Iko Iko".flac | lame -b 320 -q 0 - "Iko Iko".mp3'
2017-06-27T15:12:42.479 mp3FromFlac: OUT: 
2017-06-27T15:12:42.480 mp3FromFlac: ERROR: -cd: 1: -cd: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: the problem not in spaces. it's really matter how you execute command with pipes from groovy. `|` - the pipe is a part of shell. you have to prefix your command with `sh -c ...` or `bash -c ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to @Vampire and @dagget I had enough information to resolve this on my own. This SO [using-groovy-how-do-you-pipe-multiple-shell-commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187151/using-groovy-how-do-you-pipe-multiple-shell-commands) filled in the missing pieces. I had done this before, but long ago. Anyway, here is what I coded:

```
def cmd = ['/bin/bash', '-c', /flac -cd "${name}".flac | lame -b 320 -q 0 - "${name}".mp3/]
log "mp3FromFlac: cmd: ${cmd}"

proc = cmd.execute(null, new File(path_to_song))
```

Yes, I could have included the paths in both the flac and lame command, but as I already had this in place, that was a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't specify how you tried to call it from Groovy, I just tested a bit to show you variants:

```
/cat foo bar/.execute().err.text

Result: cat: foo: No such file or directory
cat: bar: No such file or directory
```

---

```
/cat 'foo bar'/.execute().err.text

Result: cat: 'foo bar': No such file or directory
```

---

```
/cat 'foo bar' | wc -l/.execute().err.text

Result: cat: unknown option -- l
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
```

---

```
/sh -c 'cat "foo bar" | wc -l'/.execute().err.text

Result: cat: 'foo bar': No such file or directory
```

---

```
(/cat 'foo bar'/.execute() | /wc -l/.execute()).in.text

Result: 0
```

So if you use quotes, they properly escape spaces. But you cannot use a pipe of course, as this is a shell construct. So you either have to wrap your call in `sh -c` or do the piping in Groovy instead of in your command.