# Convert text file to json with proper key value pair

Tags: json, sed

I have created one text file with all groupId which I have collected 
from pom.xml and wanted to compare with predefined configuration it's 
done using sed sh command. My text file is like

```
com.capgemini.psd2
org.springframework.boot
org.springframework.boot
com.capgemini.psd2
```

I wanted to convert as below format using sed/sh

```
groupId: {
     "key1":"com.capgemini.psd2"
     "key2":"org.springframework.boot"
     "key3":"org.springframework.boot"
     "key4": "com.capgemini.psd2"}
```

Comment: first post your humble solution attempt, than we consider how to progress. You might get better results/solutions. By including the whole task, with sample input and sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you would probably be better off using something like `jq` or `python` for processing JSON/XML data, `sed` is not ideal for pre-post processing. This solution proposes to use `awk`.

Considering you want NR to be keynum.

```
awk '
BEGIN {print "groupId: {"}
{print "\"key" NR "\":" "\""$0 "\""}
END {print "}"}' file
```

Output:

```
groupId: {
"key1":"com.capgemini.psd2"
"key2":"org.springframework.boot"
"key3":"org.springframework.boot"
"key4":"com.capgemini.psd2"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... I am using DSL (Groovy) how to include awk inside code because it's giving me java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'awk' found among steps error

Comment: Have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187151/using-groovy-how-do-you-pipe-multiple-shell-commands

Comment: created provided command into code ['awk', 'BEGIN{print "groupId": {"} {print "\"key" NR "\":" "\""$0 "\""} END {print "}"}" ${env.WORKSPACE}/project/groupFile'].execute() but still failing can you please help me out to write this code below I have written my groovy code..

Comment: sh "sed '/pom.xml/d' -i ${env.WORKSPACE}/project/groupFile"
                  sh "sed '/-- <dependency>/d' -i ${env.WORKSPACE}/project/groupFile"
                  sh "sed '/-- /d' -i ${env.WORKSPACE}/project/groupFile"
                  sh "sed 's/^[ \t]*//' -i ${env.WORKSPACE}/project/groupFile"
                  sh (script: ['awk', 'BEGIN{print "groupId": {"} {print "\"key" NR "\":" "\""$0 "\""} END {print "}"}" ${env.WORKSPACE}/project/groupFile'].execute())