# How to create functional pipes for functions/methods in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, functional-programming

I want to create pipes to connect Groovy function (method) calls like its done in other functional languages, such as F#:

```ml
 let print message =
     printf "%s" message

 // "Hello World" will be passed as a parameter to the print function
 "Hello World" |> print
```

There is a naive implementation using the `or` operator:

```java
Object.metaClass.or { it -> it(delegate)}

def print = { msg ->
    println msg
}

"Hello World" | print      //Hello World
```

But it only works for functions with 1 parameter. For more parameters, `rcurry` has to be used:

```java
Object.metaClass.or { it -> it(delegate)}

def print = { msg1, msg2 ->
    println msg1 + msg2
}

"Hello World" | print.rcurry('!!!')   //Hello World!!!
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `rcurry` method and make the Groovy code more similar to F#'s? BTW, this naive implementation only works for Groovy script files. How do I make it work also for class files?

Notice: There are other [questions about pipes in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187151/using-groovy-how-do-you-pipe-multiple-shell-commands) but these are about pipes for shell commands not functions.

Comment: Does [varargs](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_varargs) help you?

Comment: @dilvan, what is the reason for this?

Comment: I like to program in a functional style and 'pipes' is the only basic functional style Groovy is missing.

Comment: For those of us who don't know F#, can you give the example of how the multiparameter stuff would look in F#?

Comment: `let sum3 x y z = x+y+z`  is called: `3 |> sum3 1 2`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want `with` and using `.&` to convert methods to Closures, and `>>` for function composition.

```
public static String addExclamations(String s) { 
    return s + "!!!"
} 

Closure printUppercase = { String s -> println s.toUpperCase() }

"Hello World".with (this.&addExclamations >> printUppercase)
```

A real world example I find myself using all the time:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

[a:[b:'c', d:'e']].with (JsonOutput.&toJson >> JsonOutput.&prettyPrint)
```

I'm not sure what you're getting at with the multiparameter stuff, because the various `curry` solutions seem sensible to me, but you've dismissed that... perhaps I can edit this answer if you can give an example of how you would like it to look?

Comment: Nice syntax. Would you know how to implement my naive solution (using the or operator) using Groovy Extension Modules?