# Groovy Script implementation and filtering the result

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I have this groovy script :

```
def response = ["curl", "-X", "GET", "-H", "X-Auth-Key: key", "-H", "X-Auth-Email: mail", "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones?page=1&per_page=1000"].execute().text

println $(response)
```

This script is working for me and its given me all the necessary information i want from Cloudflare api.

The task i want to have now is to **grep** the result of the command like that :

```
grep -Po '(?<="name":")[^"]*' | grep -v "string" | grep -v "string" | grep -v "string" | grep -v "string".
```

Can someone help me to integrate these **grep** to the result of the Groovy script ?

Thank you,
Theo

Comment: the pipe - `|` - is a shell  feature. so to use pipe you have to start shell that starts curl & grep.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187151/using-groovy-how-do-you-pipe-multiple-shell-commands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using groovy, how do you pipe multiple shell commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187151/using-groovy-how-do-you-pipe-multiple-shell-commands)

Comment: Why just don't use grep() method from Groovy itself?

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#grep()