# Gradle execute a command with spaces and pipe output while running

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to do an Xcode build in Gradle. Requirements:

- Some of my arguments have spaces in them.
- I want to pipe the output through xcpretty. Otherwise gitlab complains that there is too much output and I can't see any errors toward the end of the build
- I don't want to wait for the command to complete before seeing the output. I want to be able to watch it build, like any ci job

Gradle exec{} doesn't seem to let me pipe the output while building. I can save the output to a file but that doesn't let me watch the build

I.e.,

```
exec {
    executable 'xcodebuild'
    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
    args = [
            'archive',
            '-project',
            "${buildDir}/iPhone/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/",
            "-archivePath",
            "${buildDir}/iPhone/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive",
            "-sdk", "iphoneos",
            "GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES",
            "DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym",
            "DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT=NO",
            "DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=iOS_Dsym",
            "DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES",
            "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=RPGSNMH65P",
            "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=${appleIdentity}",
            "CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual",
            "USYM_UPLOAD_AUTH_TOKEN=${appcenter_login_token}",
            "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER_APP=${provisioningProfile}",
            "-configuration", "Release",
            "-scheme", "${schemeName}",
            "| xcpretty"
    ]
}
```

doesn't work

I can't use groovy "xcodebuild ... CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=${"${appleIdentity}"} ... | xcpretty".execute() because my code signing identity contains spaces and for some reason groovy wants to stick its own quotes into the command string when it finds spaces.

I tried the array execute method but ended up with the same problem.

```
def cmd = [
        'xcodebuild ',
        'archive',
        '-project',
        "${buildDir}/iPhone/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/",
        "-archivePath",
        "${buildDir}/iPhone/Unity-iPhone.xcarchive",
        "-sdk", "iphoneos",
        "GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES",
        "DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym",
        "DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT=NO",
        "DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=iOS_Dsym",
        "DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES",
        "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=RPGSNMH65P",
        "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=${appleIdentity}",
        "CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual",
        "USYM_UPLOAD_AUTH_TOKEN=${appcenter_login_token}",
        "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER_APP=${provisioningProfile}",
        "-configuration", "Release",
        "-scheme", "${schemeName}"
]
println cmd
def proc = cmd.execute()
```

... except that it's even harder to debug because I can't see the actual command being executed.

I have found various solutions online but nothing that fits these requirements

Comment: Pipe is a shell feature. So, your command should be shell/bash to use pipe.. you could create sh with all required args and pipe and just run it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187151/using-groovy-how-do-you-pipe-multiple-shell-commands

Comment: Thanks for the link daggett. I had not seen that one and it seems like the exact answer I was looking for.